# Netbeans: Maven project import another non-maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Using Net-beans, I have created a maven project and this maven project need to import another non-maven project to it.

Is that possible, if yes, Can I know how to do it?

Comment: This might help you : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#NBDAG366

Comment: I thought you know maven, thats why but I am assuming that the second project is a dependency to your maven project if this is the case then go and have a look at the maven doc about how to specify the dependency, then import your first project(without maven) build it and execute mvn command(from document to install it to your .m2 folder) and then import your maven project.

Comment: If you don't understand what I mean by mvn command, I did something for sql server driver : hope it might help you : http://claude.betancourt.us/add-microsoft-sql-jdbc-driver-to-maven/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not the best way.

I have a workaround. Add these dependency statements to pom.xml. Build this maven project after building ABC project which is a non-maven project in Netbeans.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>C:\NetbeansProjects\CloudProject\abc\dist\abc.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```